# How do I go about building a Dashboard App using MOSS '07

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How is it different from normal ASP.net development?
Anyone has valuable cool links/videos/tutorials  for what I am trying to do?

I am a newbie at sharepoint stuff..but I am pretty comfortable with ASP.net.

EDIT: The application is more like a Teamsite/Dashboard app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint is a much more restrictive framework than plain ASP.NET.  There's a lot done for you already, but the object model can be hard to work with at times.  There are some limitations that seem to be arbitrary (i.e., number of webs per site collection, number of libraries per site collection, etc, etc).  Permissions aren't terribly fine-grained, and if you need to do something that is already done but done poorly (or just not what you need), then you'll end up resorting to things like writing your own HTTP module to jump out in front of Sharepoint.

What kind of dashboard application are you building?  The web part system in WSS 3.0 and MOSS 2007 have converged, so if you just need to have a bunch of custom web parts and allow your users to build sites and use those web parts, Sharepoint may work great for you.  On the other hand, if you have specific user management needs or are going to be storing and retrieving massive amounts of data, it may not be the best thing.  It *really* depends on your application.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Microsoft PerformancePoint 2007. It exports dashboards straight to Sharepoint with no fuss. It is a very powerful tool actually, which requires little code, the bulk of the work is done in defining business rules and planning.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/performancepoint/fx101680481033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at [www.dynamicdashboards.net](http://www.dynamicdashboards.net) for Asp.Net dashboard toolkit without MOSS.